# How to convert Subquery to join?

Tags: sql, db2

Is this possible to convert the subquery by using JOIN ?

```
Select * from WB.Email WHERE CVALID = 'V' AND HSESID IN (
Select HSESID from WB.SDATA WHERE CSTART = 'Y' AND DPERIOD IN (select DPERIOD from WB.PERIOT WHERE CVALID = 'Y' ) 
        AND DJOUR = (CURRENT DATE  + 15 DAYS))
```

Comment: Your current query is invalid, it misses an ending `)` somewhere. Start with correcting that. (So we can know which query the final DJOUR condition belongs to.)

Comment: Corrected the missing )  at the end and DJOUR belongs to WB.SDATA table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.*
from WB.Email e
join WB.SDATA s on e.HSESID = s.HSESID
join WB.PERIOT p on s.DPERIOD = p.DPERIOD
where e.CVALID = 'V' 
  AND s.CSTART = 'Y'
  AND s.DJOUR = CURRENT_DATE  + 15 DAYS
  AND p.CVALID = 'Y'
```

Perhaps you need to do `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicates.

Comment: @RohiniKumari, note that you are expected to upvote and/or accept answers that have answered your question.